# serviceNotAvailable when accessing drives with app permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

This "drives" me crazy... I have an AAD app with following application permissions with Admin Consent:

- Directory.Read.All
- Files.ReadWrite.All
- Group.Create
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- GroupMember.ReadWrite.All
- Member.Read.Hidden
- Organization.ReadWrite.All
- People.Read.All
- Sites.FullControl.All
- Sites.ReadWrite.All
- User.Read

Request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/drive/root
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "serviceNotAvailable",
    "message": "The service is not available. Try the request again after a delay. There may be a Retry-After header.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5ad04144-d8af-48ef-b9d3-43dafedb5911",
      "date": "2020-02-15T13:28:08"
    }
  }
}
```

Decoded Token:

[image: tokenimage]

There's no Retry header and I've tried for several hours now.

If I send the query using a token generated with Authorization Code grant and the scope `Group.ReadWrite.All User.Read profile openid email`, it works like a charm.

Comment: How are you obtaining the token (you cannot have both Application and Delegated scopes within a single token)?

Comment: hi marc, for sure that's not possible. App permissions  is granttype clientcredentials with scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

delegated is granttype auth_code with scope "Group.ReadWrite.All User.Read profile openid email"

Comment: Are you able to upload/download items to this Group's Drive using the UI?

Comment: yes. Even  graph calls working properly as soon as i'm connection with a token generated with user context....

Comment: funny stuff if i query for group metadata i'll get a response
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/76483fab-f9be-4efa-b5a9-xxxxxxxxxx/

repsonse:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
    "id": "76483fab-f9be-4efa-b5a9-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "classification": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-02-16T21:12:22Z",
    "creationOptions": [
        "Team",
        "ExchangeProvisioningFlags:3552"
    ],
    "description": "Teams Rollout",

Comment: According to the docs, you need `Mail.ReadWrite` permission for this. Could you confirm that is being assigned in the token you're getting?

Comment: i've just updated the initial post with a screenshot from the claims of the token.
yes, Mail.ReadWrite is there....

Comment: anyone an idea? im really stuck...

Comment: Do you get the same result if your request `/drive` (no root) or `/drive/root/children`?